# SLF4J API Loggers: Singletons or Multitons?

Tags: java, logging, memory-management, singleton, slf4j

When you have SLF4J's API jar (`slf4j-api-x.x.x.jar`) and a binding on your runtime class path, you can use code like:

```
Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());
logger.debug("Some debug message");
```

**Does SLF4J conveniently cache `Logger` instances (based on the specied class) for you, or is it just returning a new `Logger` every time?**

For instance, if I have:

```
Logger logger1 = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Widget.class);
Logger logger2 = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Widget.class);
Logger logger3 = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Widget.class);
logger1.debug("Some debug message");
```

Are the loggers (`logger1`, `logger2` and `logger3`) all the same instance/memory reference or are they 3 separate logger instances, all configured to log on behalf of the `Widget` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes SLF4J does perform caching on the loggers.

Answer (score 0):

All three should be references to the same object. Note that this is trivial to test for yourself with `logger1 == logger2`.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily test that yourself. Just make a check logger1 == logger2 == logger3. If Logger is an instance-controlled class which caches and reuses its instances, the references will point to the same object. If, instead it returns a new logger every time, your check would return false.